# restrict permissions on a java, c++, python program

Tags: java, python, c++, security

Suppose I have to run a java, c++, or python3.8 program on my machine, but I don't want these programs to access my system information, run os commands, or perform any malicious activity. Is there a way to do this for each of the aforementioned languages?

Comment: Restrict the user that is used to run the process?

Comment: The application involves a client creating their own code and running it on my machine via a rest api.

Comment: You're allowing users to run arbitrary code on your machine? That's a *terrible* idea.

Comment: Nothing can protect you from sufficiently advanced malware. And code that technically isn't malware can still starve the system of resources.

Comment: Note that asking for how to mitigate the threat in three different programming languages dooms the question to being too broad. Ask about one language, and preferably narrow the question further to  target specific classes of malware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java theoretically has a solution for this: The 'SecurityManager'. You can set one up within your java code (you can tell the system: Here is some code; load it as the manager please).

A securitymanager gets called before certain things happen and can deny the operation. It's mostly anything that feels security sensitive:

- Quitting the VM
- Opening any file
- Opening any network connection
- Setting the security manager
- accessing clipboards
- Printing things
- Can influence certain aspects of thread loading

You'd tell java to run some class file that you wrote, that class file sets up a security manager, and will then run the application you want to restrict.

Note that you can't really restrict how much memory and/or CPU it uses with a SecurityManager, which can be quite an issue by itself.

The problem is, the primary use case for this mechanism is to run applets, and applets are *long* dead. Thus, it's a feature that few people in the java ecosystem are currently using, and little-used blacklist-style mechanisms are usually riddled with holes.

I'd strongly suggest you set up a virtual machine for this purpose. There are leaks in hypervisor based restrictions too, but 'host things in a VM and ensure it cant do things to the underlying machine' is a lot more common.

Comment: Yes, I think SecurityManager will work for my application. Do you know of equivalents for c++, and python?